# Django: Wish to have my css file located in my project instead of an app

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to save my style.css file in the main project folder (for my project in django that is) under either /static/ or /templates/ but I cannot seem to load it properly. I use:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static '/style.css' %}" \>
```

This css file is suppose to be loaded with my /templates/base.html site (stored in the main project folder).

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 1):

Loading of static files from `templates` directory is a bad idea - source of your templates will be available to web user.

To load files from `static/` directory add the `STATICFILES_DIRS` to your `settings.py`:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)
```

And BTW remove the first slash in the `{% static %}` tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'style.css' %}" \>
```